# Salesforce Connecting two orgs through API

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, metadata-api, soap

I want to be able to access an org's metadata from a visualforce page in another org.

My needs are:

1. Connecting my org (acme) to another org (acme2)
2. From a visualforce page in acme, I want to be able to retrieve all api names for objects/fields given the type. So if I specify Apex Page as the api in my visualforce, I want to query all visualforce pages in acme 2 but I only want their api name.

As long as I can get a sense of how to expose the orgs to eachother, I can figure out the rest. How do i go about establishing such a connection?

In nun shell looking for answer of following questions:

1) Can we call salesforce API from another org (using apex)?

2) Need high level steps to achieve this.

3) Is there any reference link(blog/workbook/video) on how to implement this 
with sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SOAP or REST api from apex for this.

Here are steps for SOAP api.

1) download the partner wsdl and generate a apex class from partner wsdl.
2) call login api from proxy class (generated in above step) get session id
3) using this session id you can call other APIs like query and list all classes & pages

Here is video tutorial for the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sTcouxZyCo